# Regarding robust standard errors

Tags: regression

My model's residuals suffers from auto-correlation and heteroskedasticity. Can anybody list all the possible options. I know one possible option is Newey-west standard errors. Please tell me what are some other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have autocorrelated residuals, maybe a different model would be more appropriate?  If you have heteroskedasticy, maybe try a Box-Cox transform?

Comment: Hi: sometimes correlated residuals can be dealt with by assuming some structure for the error term. For example, an AR(1) possibly. But note that, in this case, the model can't be estimated by least squares. One needs to maximize the likelihood numerically.